# Does the infinite product of the reciprocals of a decreasing (or increasing) function equal zero?

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product, conjectures

I've made a short document explaining what I've just claimed. I'd like to know if the criteria for the infinite product to be zero is enough to hold for all decreasing and increasing functions. 
[Theorem.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zkRI3Uf361fqudCuffTrX0zAFQ6zFvrX/view?fbclid=IwAR3y9_QsbN2nN_LN6FIq2UDC0RBOb2CtTq5nzWMw6eyIpsMiDOB72n5Yczs)

Comment: It might help to use a form of $\LaTeX$ called MathJax here. Please [edit] the question to include the details of the claim.

Comment: I don't think this not true in general, see [Wallis Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)

Comment: Certainly this is not true.  If the function increases or decreases to a limiting value of $1$, and the convergence to $1$ is sufficiently rapid (this can be made precise), then the product does not diverge to zero.

Comment: Product  of decreasing sequence where numbers converge to a point less than 1 will converge to 0. In general this not true

Comment: But if the function increases or decreases on some interval (a,∞), it's continous and different than zero for every f(a+n) then the product must approach zero, I've put some restrictions to avoid an undefined expression and clearly stated that the function must increase in the whole interval (a,∞)

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean, the function can be infinitely increasing to a value that can be less than 1 and therefore the infinite product wouldn't approach zero...

Comment: I've updated the document, for the infinite product to converge to zero of an increasing function, it requires that the function takes values greater than 1, that is to say that the limit as n approaches infinity of f(a+n)>1 and likewise, the infinite product of the reciprocals of a decreasing function will converge to zero if the limit as n approaches infinity of f(b+n)<-1, only under these conditions will the infinite product approach zero.

Comment: No proofs.  Looks amaturish.  What does for all a + n in R signify?  Isn't a fixed?

Comment: a and n are real numbers, and yes, a is fixed.

Comment: It means that f(a+n) is different than zero for every (a+n) input that the function takes, if some value equals zero then the infinite product will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite products are fun.  Check out Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis* (Theorem 15.5, page 322).  There Rudin gives a clear (and simple) proof of the fact that an infinite product of "fractions"  $0 < 1 - u_n \leq 1$ converges to a nonzero (positive) value exactly when the complementary sequence of fractions $0 ≤ u_n < 1$  is summable.  In symbols, $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n < \infty \iff \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-u_n) >0 .$$